# How can the 30-pin iPhone cable go from 4 USB connections to 30?

Tags: usb, charger, data

The old apple USB goes from having 4 wires on the usb side (like any usb) and leads to 30 pins in a wide adapter. I feel like there might be some kind of data encoding that translates the usb data and branches it out to the 30 (or 15) pins. Not sure...!

[image]

Comment: A quick search for "apple 30 pin pinout" will tell you exactly what's going on in that connector.

Comment: I don't see a question but "feelings" of this type don't really translate to proper engineering questions.

Answer (score 1):

The USB to 30 Pin dock connector has a 1 to 1 connection for USB. Only 4 of the pins in the 30 Pin dock connector are used in this case. The other pins are not used and often not even populated.